# Edit password.key then unlock phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I just did a strange thing.I went to data/system, there was password.key file.It was consisted of almost two lines of text included more numeric and few alphabets.I just edited it and add "32" at the end of second line using ES file explorer.Then I locked my phone,now i am unable to unlock it. How can I unlock my android phone without factory reset?

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed?

Comment: ROM Manager app says your phone is not listed for custom Rom